# Assigning persistent interface names, using udev, with a generalized method

Tags: raspberry-pi, udev, interface

I'm currently working on a Raspberry Pi 3, trying to do some IoT stuff. I want it to be able to sniff on a usb wireless adapter, and send its data either via default wireless adapter or ethernet. I thought I could use udev, modifying /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules. It seemed to me that I need to get the MAC address of the default wireless adapter. I got the MAC address using lshw:

> ```
> root@raspberrypi:/etc/udev# lshw -class network   
> *-usb:1             
>    description: Wireless interface
>    product: 802.11 n WLAN
>    vendor: Ralink
>    physical id: 4
>    bus info: usb@1:1.4
>    logical name: wlan1
>    version: 1.01
>    serial: 1.0
>    capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800 usbdriverversion=4.4.13-v7+ firmware=0.29 link=no maxpower=450mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn   
> *-network:0
>    description: Wireless interface
>    physical id: 2
>    logical name: wlan0
>    serial: b8:27:eb:e9:67:22
>    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>    configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmfmac driverversion=7.45.41.26 firmware=01-df77e4a7 ip=192.168.0.102 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn   
> *-network:1
>    description: Ethernet interface
>    physical id: 3
>    logical name: eth0
>    serial: b8:27:eb:bc:32:77
>    size: 100Mbit/s
>    capacity: 100Mbit/s
>    capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
>    configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=smsc95xx driverversion=22-Aug-2005 duplex=full firmware=smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=10.42.0.11 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
> ```

From this command, I can see the MAC address of my default wireless interface. Simply I'd put it in the rules and I'd be able to set the interface directly to wlan0. What I want is something more general: I don't want to do these setup in every device I set. I'll write a script and it'll get the wireless adapter's address for me.

> ```
> root@raspberrypi:/etc/udev# sudo lshw -class network | grep b8:27:eb | sed 's/^.*serial: //' 
> b8:27:eb:e9:67:22 
> b8:27:eb:bc:32:77
> ```

I used **lshw**, **grep**'d the MAC address that belonged to Raspberry Pi Foundation (b8:27:eb:xx:xx:xx), then get something like "serial: , and used **sed** to simply leave the MAC.
 Then I figured that the ethernet adapter had also MAC address with same header.
My question is, how can I get only the RPi wireless adapter's MAC address as an output of a command?

Comment: Wireless interfaces are not always named `wlan[0..n]`  for instance I saw `wlp[0..n]s0`

Comment: Raspberries I worked with had wireless interfaces starting with wlan. I guess it has something to do with kernel namespaces but I couldn't see the namespaces it has. It's not what I'm interested in, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will print the first wireless MAC   (note that I'm not sure that these addresses are called "MAC addresses" in a wireless context)

```
lshw -class network  | awk '/usb:/ {ok=0} /network:/ {ok=1} /serial:/ {serial=$2} /capabilities: .*wireless/ && ok {print serial; exit}'
```

Comment: Executed with superuser, didn't get any result; now I'm trying to figure out why I didn't get any. Thanks for you effort!

Comment: @HüseyinBilgeYağcı  I removed the "^" character in the pattern

Comment: Wow, it actually worked, but in a weird way. When I sudo'd it, it gives me $2 of then usb adapter ( which is 1.0). It gives different results based on whether it's super-user'd or not. Since I'm a newbie in awk, I'm going to read some documentation and try to solve this situation. Nonetheless, your answer gives me what I asked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @HüseyinBilgeYağcı I just corrected the bug, I added a flag to match which block usb or network is read

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the interface, you can query the MAC address with ifconfig

```
ifconfig wlan0 | grep HWaddr | cut -d ' ' -f 10-
```

**ifconfig wlan0** will print information about only that interface.

**grep HWaddr** will keep only the line that has the MAC address

**cut -d ' ' -f 10-**  will split that one line on spaces and give you what's after the 10th space until the end of the line.

Comment: I don't fully understand the opening sequence of the system, and I'd like to manipulate the interface-naming script before I logged in, also *if possible* before I named the interface wlan0. Therefore I won't be able to grep wlan0. Even though I can use **ifconfig | grep b8:27:eb**, I still can't differentiate between the ethernet and wireless adapters produced by same company. 
Thanks for your effort and have a nice day :)